# Promise.all() returns undefined array of Promise <Pending>'s, despite similar solutions returning successful alternatives

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm building a web app that allows users to view a dashboard of items, which in turn have individual sections (a, b, and c), which the dashboard will show as complete (o) or incomplete (x) as illustrated below. This allows the user to navigate directly to the page that has missing information, as all of an item's information is required to progress to the next stage.

```
Item | a | b | c | Next Stage?
------------------------------
abc  | x | o | x | No
def  | x | x | x | No
ghi  | o | o | o | Yes
```

Within each item (e.g. abc), it can have a number of sub-items which must all be completed for that item's a, b, or c section to be marked as complete. This has been achieved through a nested series of promises that update a 'completeness' variable whenever a sub-item is updated. However, **the issue** arises when attempting to transport the variable from the scope of sub-items (a's, b's, c's) to parent items (abc, def, ghi). I've previously used nested promises without implementation of async/await and as this is the final usage of a promise within the scope of this project, I'm hesitant to adopt a different way of solving this problem (but I'm not against it).

**Current Implementation:**

```
exports.loadDashboard = (req, res, next) => {
Item.find()
.where("user").equals(req.session.user)
.select()
.exec()
.then(docs => {
    const response = {
        items: docs.map(doc => {
            const aPromise = Feature.find().where("projectID").equals(doc._id).select("aComplete").exec();
            const bPromise = Feature.find().where("projectID").equals(doc._id).select("bComplete").exec();
            const cPromise = Feature.find().where("projectID").equals(doc._id).select("cComplete").exec();
            Promise.all([aPromise, bPromise, cPromise]).then(result => {
                return{
                    _id: doc._id,
                    user: doc.user,
                    aComplete: result[0],
                    bComplete: result[1],
                    cComplete: result[2]
                }
            // })
        }
    ),
    userSessionID: req.session.user   
    }
    if(req.session.user != null){
        console.log(response);
        res.render("dashboard", {response});
    }else{
        res.redirect("login");
    }
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
        error: err
    });
});
```

}

...which grants a `response` of:

```
{  items: [ undefined, undefined, undefined ],
 userSessionID: '1' }
```

These undefined items are of type `Promise <Pending>`, and similar issues have been solved in similar manners, but this time I'm quite stuck. My question is, is it possible to solve this without delving into async/await, or should I bite the bullet, and if that's the case I'd be most grateful for any assistance provided.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Don't try building everything up in your response object.   Do your `Promise.all`, and then from it's `then` callback, build your response.   Otherwise your returning your response before it's even complete,.

Comment: Thanks @Keith, although I'm not sure I understand - I'm already building my response within the the `Promise.all`'s `then` callback, aren't I? I can't see how I can call the `Promise` functions any earlier than where I've called them as I need the `doc` scope to grab the `_id`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on here and if possible, switch to using async/await instead of using Promises, since this is one of the main reasons that makes your code rather hard to maintain. I believe you might just have to actually return the correct values.

Your .map function doesn't return anything, which might be the main reason, you're receiving [undefined, undefined, undefined].

```
exports.loadDashboard = (req, res, next) => {
// don't use "where", if you don't have to
Item.find({user: req.session.user)
.exec()
.then(docs => {
  const items = docs.map(doc => {
            const aPromise = Feature.find().where("projectID").equals(doc._id).select("aComplete").exec();
            const bPromise = Feature.find().where("projectID").equals(doc._id).select("bComplete").exec();
            const cPromise = Feature.find().where("projectID").equals(doc._id).select("cComplete").exec();
            // THIS IS WHERE I ADDED THE RETURN!
            return Promise.all([aPromise, bPromise, cPromise])
             .then(result => {
                return {
                    _id: doc._id,
                    user: doc.user,
                    aComplete: result[0],
                    bComplete: result[1],
                    cComplete: result[2]
                }
            }
       )})
  return Promise.all(items);
})
.then(items => {
    const response = {
       userSessionID: req.session.user,
       items
    };
    // also check if .user is undefined, the null check is then optional
    if(!req.session.user || req.session.user === null){
      return res.redirect("login");
    }
    console.log(response);
    return res.render("dashboard", {response});
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).json({error});
});
```

and see how it goes. I believe there might still be some issues, but that outline should make it easier for you to work with it.

Comment: Absolutely phenomenal, this works exactly as I'd hoped it would. Seriously major thanks to yourself BenSower and @Keith for your input and assistance!

Comment: No problem. As I already mentioned, I recommend you having a look into the newer async/await Syntax, which makes writing this code way easier and cleaner.

Comment: I definitely will, this project was a foolhardy jump into an unknown universe of NoSQL and asynchronous code, but at least next time I'll be (slightly more) prepared!